# Change location of animated armature

Tags: animation, armature, bones, baking

I have an armature which is animated using bone rotation as well as object location. I'm trying to duplicate it and move it to another location but it's not working as there are some keyframes changing the location of the armature. I tried baking the animation but then the armature no longer moves around the scene. Any advice please?

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You animated the movement of the armature in object mode, but you should always use a root or ground bone in pose mode to animate the movement: [Root bone as pelvis vs ground?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70823/root-bone-as-pelvis-vs-ground)

What you can do if you don't want to redo the whole movement animation is parent the object armature to an empty and use it to move or rotate said armature.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the graphs u can also move them to get ur character into position.
When in graph view select the root bone, press the arrow to reveal more then use the graphs that move the model the direction you want.
For example u can go to the first frame of ur animation and using the location graphs move the curves (in their entirety) up and down till it’s where you want it to be.